# Mysql Count per column

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.feeder_id, b.feeder_pr
FROM authors_article_feeders a
LEFT JOIN feeders b ON b.id = a.feeder_id
WHERE website_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

which results in:

```
feeder_id   feeder_pr
18          2
18          2
18          2
18          2
32          6
```

What I need is to modify the above query so that it will manipulate this data so that the result would end up with a count of each feeder_pr, so in this case the result would be:

```
feeder_pr   count
2           4
6           1
```

Any assistance is appreciated.  If you have time please describe your solution so that I can learn from it while I'm at it.

Everything I've tried has ended in inaccurate results, usually with just one row instead of the expected 2.

Comment: What you need is  `select b.feeder_pr,count(b.feeder_pr) group by b.feeder_pr` with your existing joins, you may not by giving the `group by` thats why you end up with one row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY` And, you would not even need the joins

```
SELECT b.feeder_pr, COUNT(b.feeder_pr)
FROM feeders b 
GROUP BY b.feeder_pr
```

Comment: No problem, please don't forget that appreciation is best shown with a checkmark :)

Comment: :) I plan to in 4 minutes when it will let me ;)

Comment: Oh haha, I didnt realize there was a time limit on that. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure what it is, maybe 10-15 minutes or so after the initial question is asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.feeder_pr, count(a.feeder_id) as count
FROM authors_article_feeders a
LEFT JOIN feeders b ON b.id = a.feeder_id
WHERE website_id =1
GROUP BY 1
```